# setting a default launcher

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, launcher, samsung-galaxy-note, default-applications, adw-launcher-ex

Ok so I rooted my samsung galaxy note 10.1 today. I immediately bought the full version of adw launcher and installed it. Now I have a bit of experience with Android and launchers so I have tried all the usual methods of setting a default launcher.

I tried the home key then "always use" method. I tried clearing the default on the stock launcher. And I've been looking at other methods but none sound like anything I want to risk doing with my new 500 dollar tablet.

Does anyone know of a simple and straight forward method of setting a default launcher?

EDIT:: It was asking me to select a default launcher despite the fact that i had said that i want it to always use ADW EX. In the end the solution was to simply use Titanium Backup and remove all the other launchers. =)

(Sent from my rooted Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 using Google Chrome)

Comment: Exactly as you described. Is there any problem? If so, it would make sense to state what is happening, and what you would have expected instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be fixed by removing the other apps that are available to be used.

After all if there is only one option, that HAS to be the default right?

A good tool for this is titanium backup. It is for root users so if you do not have root you will have to find some other way of removing the app (adb would probably be your best option if you refuse to root your phone)

Answer (score 1):

The simple and straightforward method to set the default launcher is the one you used:

1. Tap the Home button.
2. Tap **ADW.Launcher**.
3. Tap **Always**.

If this isn't working for some reason, then it might help to describe what the device is doing instead.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. I apologize for not having gotten back to you sooner on this post. I have edited the OP with the details of the misadventure. Up voted for being a good sport... =P

Comment: @KonnerRasmussen Welcome to [android.se]. Since you solved your own problem, you should post it as an Answer, and then accept it by clicking the check mark next to your own answer.